# How are values assigned to the result of a function call?

Tags: r

I'm just starting to learn R and, in the tutorial I am following, the following type of syntax gets used often:

```
function(variable) <- value
```

To give a specific example:

```
width(myIRange) <- 3
```

In Python I know this would be `myIRange.width = 3` which would just be setting the attribute of the `myIRange` object. Since, in R, `width` is just a function, how does setting the result of calling it on `myIRange` actually affect `myIRange`?

Comment: `function(variable) <-`value This is syntactic sugar for `\`function<-\`(variable, value)`; it's  a separate function that could do anything but typically modifies the variable in place.

Comment: These are called *"assignment functions"*. Your `with(.) <- 3` is actually a function named `\`width<-\` <- function(x, val) { ... }` (I don't know the real arg names, but it's two). The "special" about them is that the function name has `<-` appended to it, and R then allows it to be on the LHS of an assignment (whether `<-` or `=`).

Comment: It is not quite the same as python's `myIRange.width`, since that suggests that the `myIRange` object has a property named `width`; in the case of R's assignment operators, that function can do *anything* to the value assigned, whereas in the case of object properties, it is just value assignment.

Comment: So, the `width` is overloaded? There is a `width` that just takes a variable and returns some value about it and there is a `width` that takes a variable and a value, uses the value to modify the variable and returns nothing?

Comment: This is not overloading. It is an explicit function written that does *something* to the object `myIRange`. It might store `value` as an attribute of the object (such as what `\`names<-\`` does). "Overloading" is more of a topic related to S3 method dispatch or similar OO/polymorphism. An assignment function is not overloading.

Comment: Its operation is almost purely in *side-effect*, which is counter to the more common (though not absolute) *functional* aspect of many of R's functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can show what's going on more clearly by writing a little function to create objects of S3 class "box", to represent a box with a specified height, width and length:

```r
make_box <- function(height, width, length) {
    structure(list(height = height, width = width, length = length), 
              class = "box")
}
```

We also want a function to be able to retrieve the width of `box` objects:

```r
width <- function(b)
{
  if(class(b) != "box") stop("Can only get width of objects of class box")
  return(b$width)
}
```

For clarity, we will also define a print method for our `box` class:

```
print.box <- function(b) {
  cat("A box of dimension", paste(b$height, b$width, b$length, sep = " x "),
      "and volume", b$height * b$width * b$length)
}
```

So now we can create a `box`:

```r
my_box <- make_box(height = 1, width = 2, length = 3)

my_box
#> A box of dimension 1 x 2 x 3 and volume 6
```

And extract its width:

```
width(my_box)
#> [1] 2
```

However, if we try to assign a new width using the assignment syntax, we throw an error:

```r
width(my_box) <- 3
#> Error in width(my_box) <- 3: could not find function "width<-"
```

Notice that there is no such function. We need to tell R what we mean with this syntax:

```r
`width<-` <- function(b, value)
{
  b$width <- value
  return(b)
}
```

So now when we do:

```r
width(my_box) <- 3
```

We get no error, and we can see that `my_box` has had its `width` member updated:

```r
my_box
#> A box of dimension 1 x 3 x 3 and volume 9
```

This works because the parser knows that if we are using the "assign to a function call" syntax, then it's supposed to look for the appropriate subassignment function. It therefore effectively interprets `width(my_box) <- 3` as `my_box <- 'width<-'(my_box, 3)`

<sup>Created on 2021-09-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: This is a very helpful example. I am surprised, though, that the assignment function returns the updated object with `return(b)`. I expected it to do something like `assign(deparse(substitute(b)), b, envir=globalenv())` because `b` is updated in the global environment and not actually "returned". Is this a specific behavior of all functions whose name ends with `<-`?

Comment: @benimwolfspelz yes, it's a little counterintuitive. It's because the parser knows that if we are using the "assign to a function call" syntax, then it's supposed to look for the appropriate subassignment function. It therefore effectively interprets `width(my_box) <- 3` into `my_box <- 'width<-'(my_box, 3)`.